# Highlight the full text searched on vi editor?

Tags: search, highlight, debugging

We've only vi editor on servers (There are 100+ of them so installing vim in each of them is not really an option as that's not our servers as we're just providing a service to others).

No installation privileges.

Tell me how can I achieve full text highlight of what is searched in this case?

For vim there is :set hlsearch and search by typing *, what's there for vi editor? Any workarounds?

I need to read lots of logs and this is absolutely essential feature to have.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved
~
~                                                            version 7.4.629
~                                                       by Bram Moolenaar et al.
~                                                   Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
~                                              Vim is open source and freely distributable
~
```

Update:

```
egrep -i "error|fail" /var/log/messages | less
```

The problem with this is that we have to search using phone number like 0123456789 and doing this will skip the lines that do not contain the phone number, which loses the whole point of grep.

```
2023-08-07 09:20:35 0123456789 INFO  CustomerLogoutResource:95 - Entering logout api.
2023-08-07 09:20:35 0123456789 ERROR AppExceptionMapper:87 - Exception has been thrown by container
2023-08-07 09:20:35 0123456789 ERROR AppExceptionMapper:555 - Unchecked Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at NullPointerExceptionExample.printLength(NullPointerExceptionExample.java:3)
    at NullPointerExceptionExample.main(NullPointerExceptionExample.java:8)
```

Like this is what I mean.

Comment: What vi, exactly? Could you add the full output of `:version`? Something like `Version 4.0 (gritter) 3/25/05`?

Comment: 7.4.629. It says it's VIM

Comment: I asked for the full output, to see which features are built-in and which are not. But it looks like you may be able to close this question and leverage all your Vim-fu against those logs.

Comment: No when I try :set hlsearch, it says set command not found!

Comment: Again, let's see the full output of :version

Comment: version command not found @romainl

Comment: try `vim --version`

Comment: vim command not found.

Comment: `vi --version`?

Comment: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 13 2020 16:12:33)
Included patches: 1-207, 209-629
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>`

Comment: What you posted is useless. I asked for the ***FULL*** output and you should add it to the question instead of burying it in the comments anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Quite frankly, you should consider using `less(1)` and `grep(1)` to view the log files on your servers.  See, a text editor is used primarily to *edit* text, while other utilities are used primarily to *view* text.

Moreover, not using `vi` or `vim` to view large log files is more efficient and would save some resources on your servers, because no large swap files would be created.  No matter how small, it all adds up.

If you decide to use `less(1)` and `grep(1)`, these utilites are already capable of coloring the search matches in their outputs.

Below is a screenshot that shows an example of the colored output produced by running `grep -ri pedantic` on a local copy of the `vim` source code repository.  All colors in the output are customizable, of course, this is just an example that shows my preferences.

[image: Colored grep output]

To tell `less(1)` to highlight search matches, all you need is `export LESS='--use-color -DSWr'` in your `~/.bashrc`, for example.  With that in place, the highlighted search matches in `less(1)` look just the same as in the screenshot above.

Comment: The swap files are typically removed when exiting normally, so it's only a temporary drain on resources (and can be disabled).

Comment: True, but they do consume resources temporarily in the default configuration, which only gets worse with large log files.

Comment: @dsimic see the updated question. The problem is certain lines of logs don't contain the  search keyword and we need all the lines to read the flow of program.

Comment: You can always use two `egrep` or `grep` invocations, e.g. `cat logfile | grep 01234567 | grep error | less`.  The last `grep` will end up coloring the search matches in the output, in this case `error` would be colored.

Comment: Actually, you'd need to use something like `cat logfile | grep 01234567 | grep error --color=always | less -R` to see the colored search matches.

Comment: In case there are lines in the log file that don't contain `01234567`, you can simply use `grep` to filter out all lines that contain e.g. `error`, and then use `less` to review the filtered lines, or to search further in `less` just as you'd do that in `vi` or `vim`.

Comment: Let me ping @achhainsan to make sure they'll see my comments above.

Comment: @dsimic that looks like an absolute hassle. Any hassle free solution?

Comment: @achhainsan Quite frankly, I'm not really sure what are you trying to accomplish?  Could you, please, expand your question a bit?  Perhaps a hassle-free solution would be to write some shell scripts or create some shell aliases that would perform the required filtering operations on your log files.

Comment: Let me also add that if opening the log files in `vi` or `vim` and searching them by hand is all you need, simply using `less` instead is the way to go.  Together with telling `less` to highlight the search matches, of course.

Comment: I just updated my answer to describe how to configure highlighting of the search matches in `less`.  It's rather simple.

Comment: Note that `grep` has some context arguments `ABC` to show lines around matches.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble problem with say A with grep is that I don;t know how many lines the logs for a particular user will be there.  It's very fun.

Comment: One more note: vim has a view binary that makes vim start in readonly mode, and has the readonly and modifiable options. Vim can definitely be a comfortable text viewer. Though your point is well-taken :)

Answer (score 1):

As answered by dsimic (I don't have enough points to just comment on theirs), vi is best at editing text, while other linux tools are designed for viewing/filtering.  `less` is great for those familiar with vi due to some common keys.  `Ctrl-d` (or u) in `vi` corresponds to `d` in `less`, `25%` works in both, etc. Next is grep, like:

```
egrep -i "error|fail" /var/log/messages | less
```

- `egrep` = `grep -E` = allows extended regular expressions, (I find these easier & more portable) like allowing a pipe for OR, which finds either "error OR fail" (reworded, D. Ben Knoble's comment was right, and egrep will be deprecated, while `grep -E` will continue, but my muscle memory won't stop till I'm forced to)
- `-i` = case insensitive
- `|` = pipe sends output from one command to input of the next, unless it's used in a regular expression where it means OR

Not sure if you're looking for a specific phone number, or any number, here's an example file I used:

```
$ cat a.file
2023-08-07 09:20:35 0123456789 INFO  CustomerLogoutResource:95 - Entering logout api.
2023-08-07 09:20:35 0123456789 ERROR AppExceptionMapper:87 - Exception has been thrown by container
2023-08-07 09:20:35 0123456789 ERROR AppExceptionMapper:555 - Unchecked Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at NullPointerExceptionExample.printLength(NullPointerExceptionExample.java:3)
    at NullPointerExceptionExample.main(NullPointerExceptionExample.java:8)
2023-08-07 09:20:35 INFO  CustomerLogoutResource:95 - Entering logout api.
2023-08-07 09:20:35 9999999999 INFO  CustomerLogoutResource:95 - Entering logout api.
2023-08-07 09:20:35 INFO  CustomerLogoutResource:95 - Entering logout api.
$
```

If you always know errors will be exactly 3 lines, you can just ask for the 3 after:

```
$ egrep -A3 --color 0123456789 a.file
2023-08-07 09:20:35 0123456789 INFO  CustomerLogoutResource:95 - Entering logout api.
2023-08-07 09:20:35 0123456789 ERROR AppExceptionMapper:87 - Exception has been thrown by container
2023-08-07 09:20:35 0123456789 ERROR AppExceptionMapper:555 - Unchecked Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at NullPointerExceptionExample.printLength(NullPointerExceptionExample.java:3)
    at NullPointerExceptionExample.main(NullPointerExceptionExample.java:8)
$
```

If you don't know how many lines come after, I'd have to resort to perl for a multiline search.  I've never found great ways to do multiline searches, sorry it's a bit complicated.  Note the date will change, but if I just put "2023" you might not see how to update it:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'while (/^(.*0123456789.*?)(?:^2023-08-07)/msg) { print $1 }' a.file
```

- `-e` = allow perl to operate in this one-liner mode
- `-0777` = changes the line separator to undef, letting us to slurp everything, feeding all the lines to Perl in one go.
- `-n` = assume 'while (<>) { ... }' loop around program, each line is in $_
- `while` = starts another inner loop
- `/^(.*0123456789.*?)` = look for a particular phone number.  If you wanted any phone number, you could replace just the number part with more regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065327/how-can-i-parse-a-phone-number-in-perl).
- `(?:^2023-08-07)` = begin a 2nd regex group, separate from the first group since 1st group is the result we want to see.  2nd group is just the endcap so we can stop searching for this entry and go on to the next in the loop.
- `/msg` = multiline search in perl.  Honestly this is super complicated, each of these individually I think means almost the same, but I stopped when I got it to work.
- `print $1` = print the result of the first regex found (since they're separated by parenthesis).

Comment: The problem with this is that we've to search by phone number like '0123456789', and there are lines that don't contain phone number, grep will fail here. Any better suggestions?

Comment: `grep -E` is slightly more portable than `egrep`. And without `-E`, you can still write `'error\|fail'`.